# Como alterar cor da linha da tabela baseado no valor de uma célula?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preciso fazer com que a linha da tabela altere para uma cor determinada baseada no valor contido dentro da tag 'td'.
Todas as functions que eu encontrei até agora, não me foram úteis, pois tentei implementar no meu código e não obtive sucesso.

```
                <tr>
                    <td id="IDbatchID">010203</td>
                    <td id="IDproduct">Leite</td>
                    <td id="IDbatchSize">30000</td>
                    <td id="IDpriority">1</td>
                    <td id="IDstartReq">03-31-2017 08:00:00</td>
```

Baseado no valor dentro desta 'td' eu preciso que ele altere a cor da 'tr'. Por exemplo, como aqui está 'Completed', preciso que a linha inteira fique verde.

```
                    <td id="IDstatus">Completed</td>
                </tr>
```

Não sei se eu consegui ser claro na minha dúvida. Peço ajuda, pois tudo o que eu encontrei até agora não me serviu.

Comment: Não está claro o suficiente. Como esse valor é carregado na td?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo no momento eles são inseridos manualmente por mim, pois ainda não tenho o banco para fazer a conexão, porém os valores serão sempre esses: (Completed, Delayed, In Process, New).

Comment: uai e pq não altera a cor da tr manualmente ao alterar o conteúdo da td?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo por que logo esses dados serão importados do banco automaticamente e eu preciso criar uma função capaz de colorir a linha de acordo com o valor que será importado.

Comment: entendi, estou estudando aqui uma solução

Comment: Já que vc é novo no site, leia este post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Aqui não é fórum para ficar colocando resolvido nos títulos. Isso é desnecessário, simplesmente marque qual resposta solucionou seu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuração:

Na linha  `var texto =  $("#idDaTabela tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6)").text();` repare que temos `tr:nth-child(1)` que faz referencia a primeira linha da tabela  e  `td:nth-child(6)` a sexta coluna dessa linha.

Caso haja mudança na tabela acerte esses parâmetros.

```js
$(function() { 
var texto =  $("#idDaTabela tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6)").text();   
var result = (texto);
     
if (result=="Completed"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#FF0000");
}else if(result=="Delayed"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#00FF00");
}else if(result=="In Process"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#0000FF");
}else if(result=="New"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#00FFFF");
}else{
 $("#idTr").css("background","#ccc");
        } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="idDaTabela" border="0">
<tr id="idTr">
<td id="IDbatchID">010203</td>
<td id="IDproduct">Leite</td>
<td id="IDbatchSize">30000</td>
<td id="IDpriority">1</td>
<td id="IDstartReq">03-31-2017 08:00:00</td>
<td id="IDstatus">Completed</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Mudando o conteudo da celula para In Process

```js
$(function() { 
var texto =  $("#idDaTabela tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6)").text();   
var result = (texto);
     
if (result=="Completed"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#FF0000");
}else if(result=="Delayed"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#00FF00");
}else if(result=="In Process"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#0000FF");
}else if(result=="New"){
 $("#idTr").css("background","#00FFFF");
}else{
 $("#idTr").css("background","#ccc");
        } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="idDaTabela" border="0">
<tr id="idTr">
<td id="IDbatchID">010203</td>
<td id="IDproduct">Leite</td>
<td id="IDbatchSize">30000</td>
<td id="IDpriority">1</td>
<td id="IDstartReq">03-31-2017 08:00:00</td>
<td id="IDstatus">In Process</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Exemplo com duas linhas

```js
$(function() { 
   var texto =  $("#idDaTabela tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6)").text();
    
var result = (texto);
    
if (result=="Completed"){
 $("#idTr2").css("background","#FF0000");
}else if(result=="Delayed"){
 $("#idTr2").css("background","#00FF00");
}else if(result=="In Process"){
 $("#idTr2").css("background","#0000FF");
}else if(result=="New"){
 $("#idTr2").css("background","#00FFFF");
}else{
 $("#idTr2").css("background","#ccc");
} 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="idDaTabela" border="0">
<tr id="idTr">
<td id="IDbatchID">010203</td>
<td id="IDproduct">Leite</td>
<td id="IDbatchSize">30000</td>
<td id="IDpriority">1</td>
<td id="IDstartReq">03-31-2017 08:00:00</td>
<td id="IDstatus">Completed</td>
</tr>


<tr id="idTr2">
<td id="IDbatchID2">010203</td>
<td id="IDproduct2">Leite</td>
<td id="IDbatchSize2">30000</td>
<td id="IDpriority2">1</td>
<td id="IDstartReq2">03-31-2017 08:00:00</td>
<td id="IDstatus2">Completed</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo meu caro, isso deu certo, porém ela só faz na primeira linha da tabela, teria como fazer para com que essa function funcione colorindo todas as linhas?

Comment: sim, vc quer dizer a tabela toda né?

Comment: Sim sim, isso mesmo, para toda a tabela.

Comment: Basta setar o id da tabela no script, ou seja, em todas as linhas $("#idTr").css  altere para $("#idDaTabela").css

Comment: eu fiz o que me falou e quando fui ver o resultado. A function alterou para a mesma cor todas as linhas, sem fazer diferença. Parece que ele pega o resultado do primeiro `IF` e atribui o valor para as demais.

Comment: então não era isso? para toda tabela? vai ler o texo da td e se for Completed vai aplicar a cor correspondente a todas as linhas, ou seja na tabela. Se mudar o texto para New vai aplicar a cor correspondente a toda a tabela

Comment: o que é preciso fazer é para cada linha ser uma cor de acordo com o valor da `<td>` Com esse código que me passou talvez eu consiga agora modificar aos poucos para se adequar ao que eu preciso, mas se você puder me ajudar será muito bem vindo!

Comment: vixi, então a pergunta seria diferente, melhor fazer outra pergunta para que a resposta dessa não fique em desacordo!